# Using dropdownlist i webpart (edit mode)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to add a checkboxlist to a webpart.  In the edit mode there will be a dropdown list that will contain field names from a list and the field selected will be used as the display for the checkboxlist entries in the webpart.

I have not be able to find any examples on how to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom `ToolPart` to create your dropdown property as such:

```
public class DropdownToolPart : ToolPart
{
  protected override void CreateChildControls()
  {
    DropDownList dropdownList = new DropDownList();

    // Code to add field names from SharePoint List to dropdownlist

    this.Controls.Add(dropdownList);

    base.CreateChildControls();
  }

  public override void ApplyChanges()
  {
    CheckBoxListWebPart myWebPart = 
      (CheckBoxListWebPart)this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart;

    //You will need to get the selected value of the dropdown by finding it 
    //in the Controls collection.
    string selectedValue = ...    

    myWebPart.CheckBoxListDisplayField = selectedValue;
  }
}
```

Your WebPart should do the following to include the `ToolPart`:

```
public class CheckBoxListWebPart: WebPart
{
  public string CheckBoxListDisplayField { get; set; }      

  public override ToolPart[] GetToolParts()
  {
    ToolPart[] toolParts = new ToolPart[1];

    DropdownToolPart myToolPart = new ToolPart();
    toolParts[0] = myToolPart;

    return toolParts;
  }
}
```

From there you should be able to create your checkboxlist in the `CreateChildControls` method of the `CheckBoxListWebPart`.  In there you will need to load the items from your SharePoint list and then use the `CheckBoxListDisplayField` value to select the exact field value from each item.

Comment: Thanks for the input.. In the ApplyChanges the webpart do not not have any controls and all property is null.. how can I fix this?